# Phalcon Oracle datetime error when time is used

Tags: oracle, datetime, phalcon

I have this save method in my model:

```
public function save($data = null, $whiteList = null){
    $res = false;
    $sql = '';
    $di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
    try {   
        $param = array("[fecha] = to_date('" . $this->fecha . "', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and [parametro_id] = :parametro_id:",
                        "bind" => array("parametro_id" => $this->parametro_id) );
        $primero = Instantaneos::findFirst($param);
        if ($primero){
            $this->instantaneo_id = $primero->instantaneo_id;
        } else {
            $sql = "select AZUL_S_INSTANTANEOS.nextval from dual";
            $result = $di->getShared('db')->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetchArray()){
                $this->instantaneo_id = $row['NEXTVAL'];
            }
        }
        $this->fecha = date('d/M/y', strtotime($this->fecha));
        $res = parent::save($data, $whiteList);
        $res = true;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $res = false;
        $this->appendMessage(new Message($ex->getMessage()));
    }
    return $res;
}
```

And it works, but, when I modify this line:

```
$this->fecha = date('d/M/y', strtotime($this->fecha));
```

With this one:

```
$this->fecha = date('d/M/y H:i:s', strtotime($this->fecha));
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1830 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

(ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)
And I need to save the time information, I try to make my own save method, with no parent::save, writing my own sql when insert or update:

```
    $sql_i = "insert into AZUL_INSTANTANEOS values(%d,%d,to_date('%s', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),%f,'%s')";
    $sql_u = "update AZUL_INSTANTANEOS set val = %f, valf = '%s' where instantaneo_id = %d";
```

And using:

```
$db->execute($sql);
```

But I get another error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <b>\app\config\services.php</b> on line <b>172</b><br />
```

I'm using:

1. XAMPP 1.8.2 (PHP Version 5.4.31, Apache/2.4.10 (Win32))
2. Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
3. Phalcon 2.1.0b

¿Any advice?, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is not fully supported in Phalcon. There is a driver in the incubator located [here](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter) that you can utilize.

Oracle also has a different syntax that Phalcon's PHQL potentially cannot recognize.

I would suggest you start by adding SQL statement logging to your application, so that you can see what is being sent to the database and then figure out how to correct it.

Have a look at [this](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html) page and scroll down to where it says `Logging SQL Statements`

Add that and have a look at what is going on with your query.